# Oracle 11g vs MySQL vs Hadoop:- benchmarking for 10^6 to 10^9 records

Tags: mysql, hadoop, oracle11g, benchmarking, bigdata

I need a benchmarking of Oracle 11g, MySQL and Hadoop for 10^6 to 10^9 records(rows in MySQL). There will be extensive data mining queries going on round the clock with real-time data. I want to know which db will be better especially in terms of some real stats. Data will certainly go beyond this in coming months.

Is there any open-source benchmarking tool for this? Or anyone has some data that can be useful?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:-**

Hadoop is not a DB. It is a distributed file system. Let me explain my requirements in a bit more detail. This is what I have right now, I have all my data in mysql, I am planning to export that to hadoop and run my data-mining algorithms on that. After the algorithms are over, The final result will then be sent to mysql to update the current data. I can't really go into specifics right now. Now the algorithms will be extensive, not exactly real-time but I'll have a cron job running to export data to hadoop every hour or 2 hours or so. We'll be analyzing current data, and if there is an update needed then also, update the old data.

The algos will be primarily based on neural networks.

What I am looking at is:- shall I run my data-mining queries in MySQL or do what I have explained above or do that by exporting data to Oracle db ?

Comment: Can you clarify what is your plan regarding Oracle? Are you planning to migrate to Oracle or are you planning to keep collecting the data in MySQL, than on regular basis export data to Oracle, do processing there, and then pull the results back into MySQL?

Comment: @olaf, thats exactly what I want to do. I would prefer hadoop as its open-source but if oracle is good enough to handle really huge data and complex mining algorithms, then it shouls also do. And we are not talking about TBs of data, probably lot more than that (PBs at some point of time).

Comment: @olaf, I am planning to kepp the data collection in mysql and export on regular basis

Comment: So, the MySQL database would be only an intermediate place to store the data and the final resting place for the data will be in Oracle, right? It should be a good approach for medium to reasonably large amounts of data. If you already payed for an Oracle license with partitions and analytics, it would be a path of least resistance. If not, you might build a small (6 node?) Hadoop cluster for the price of such Oracle license.

Comment: @olaf, I havent paid for oracle license yet.
This is how I would like to design my system:-

All frontend data comes to MySQL, exported to hadoop via sqoop. Say 10 node hadoop cluster. I will run all my data mining algos here. Then the required result set will be stored in MySQL.

Every 1 hour or so, I'll import the data (cron job), again run the algorithm on this data. If required, run the algorithm of past data as well. I want my system to get smarter everytime it runs the algorithm.

Comment: It's a good idea to put the results of your analytical queries back in MySQL. That way you can guarantee realtime access to these results.

Answer (score 1):

TPC-H benchmark would be a good start: http://www.tpc.org/tpch/default.asp. But comparing Oracle and Hadoop is pretty much comparing apples and oranges. I would imagine that for a relational database benchmarks Oracle would beat a Hadoop cluster, while if your queries can be expressed as a Map/Reduce job, Hadoop would beat Oracle on perfromance/$ basis and on scalability.

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 things to say :

```
Hadoop is "not" a DB.
Comparing un-comparable things is useless, IMHO.
```

You can't use Hadoop as a replacement to your RDBMS. It was not developed for real time stuff. Hadoop is best suited for offline batch processing kinda requirements. As @Olaf has said, you are trying to compare apples with oranges. But why do you need this?I mean by looking at your use case I feel like Haddop is not going to be of use to you.

---

In response to your edit :

The best bet would be to run queries on MySQL itself. Reasons :

1- Import/export time.

2- Implementing the desired algo is not always very easy in terms of a MR program.

3- 1 hour worth of data will not be huge enough to be qualified as BigData, IMHO.(I'm assuming you intend to process only the latest data and not the entire dataset).

Comment: Everytime new data comes, algorithm runs on current data and since it is neural algo, it keeps improving and if it finds new results, then it runs on the entire dataset dependig on new results. The idea is that the machine keeps getting smarter and fetches as relavant data as possible. So, it wont just be 1 hour data, it'l  1 hour data + the existing data.

Comment: IMHO, the best bet would be to use MySQL only at this moment. You could make use of Hadoop at a later stage, when you data actually starts crossing the the threshold of your current system.

Comment: what you are saying is correct. My system design is in a comment to Olaf's response.
But I am not looking at a short-term solution. I need a system that should work for next 2-3 years. At the rate I am gathering data, it wont take more than a month or two to reach the MySQl threshold. 

I already have 200 million rows in the MySQL corresponding table.